# xmlSchema apache in java

Tags: java, xsd

I'm using the library in java `XMLSchema` of *Apache*. 
I create a new object `XmlSchemaElement`  and set the attributes `minOccurs`, `maxOccurs` and `nillable` in this way:

```
XmlSchemaElement elem = new XmlSchemaElement();
elem.setName("element1");
elem.setNillable(false);
elem.setMinOccurs(1);
elem.setMaxOccurs(1);
```

I get this xsd:

```
<xs:element name="element1">
  ........
</xs:element>
```

I do not get the attributes **minOccurs, maxOccurs and nillable.**

how can I fix the problem?

I should get the item xsd like this:

```
<xs:element name="element1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false">
  ...
</xs:element>
```

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` can only be used when an element declaration is *nested* in a group, such as an `<xs:sequence>`. If you are creating top-level `<xs:element>` elements, it's illegal to have those attributes.

Try adding that element as a child to a group (sequence, choice, all, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The Default Value of

minOccurs - 1
maxOccurs - 1
nillable -false

That's the reason it might not be appeared.